# Если установить что-либо на одну учетку будет ли это отображаться на другой?

Tags: windows

Есть гостевая учетка, если допустим что-нибудь установить на нее, то будет ли оставаться иконка установленного приложения на раб. столе основной учетки? win7

Comment: Приложение, которое МОЖНО установить от имени учётной записи гостя, неспособно (ни при установке, ни при работе) что-то разместить на рабочем столе другой учётной записи, если ранее ей не были даны права записи в папку рабочего стола этой записи.

Answer (score 1):

В меню: только если была активирована опция "установить для всех пользователей". Впрочем, ряд приложений делают это по умолчанию при установке. Но гостю все равно необходимо получить разрешение на установку, если только не отключена защита.
Про рабочий стол - вряд ли, из под гостя подобное можно провести только при условии делегирования прав.